# Limit at infinity of cubic roots and square roots without using conjugate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+3}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+3}}   $$

How would you proceed to find this limit, by eyeballing I would guess it foes to zero since the numerator has a smaller power than the denominator, normaly I would use the binomial theorem if I had something like $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+2}-1}{\sqrt{x+3}-1}   $$ But here I don't know how to find the limit since I can't really use the binomial theorem.

Comment: For large $x$ the additive constants are neglectible and the expression tends to $x^{-1/6}$.

Comment: How would you use the binomial theorem? Because actually it is not a problem to add the -1 term, since it does not affect the limiting behavior of the fraction as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: I would put a = cubic root of (x+2) and b = 1 and choos n to be 3 so I would have (a^3-1^3)=(a-1)(a^2 + a^1 +1) so I can rewrite (a-1) as (a^3-1^3)/(a^2 + a^1 +1) and same for denominator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you factorize you get 
$$\frac{x^{1/3}(1+2/x)^{1/3}}{x^{1/2}(1+3/x)^{1/2}} = \frac{(1+2/x)^{1/3}}{x^{1/6}(1+3/x)^{1/2}} $$
I'll let you do the limit yourself.

Answer (score 14):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+3}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt[6]{\dfrac{(x+2)^2}{(x+3)^3}}=\sqrt[6]{0}=0$$

Answer (score 13):

Simply use *equivalents*: $\;\sqrt[3]{x+2}\sim_\infty \sqrt[3]{x}$, $\;\sqrt{x+3}\sim_\infty \sqrt{x}$, hence
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+3}}\sim_\infty \frac{x^{1/3}}{x^{1/2}}=x^{-1/6}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0.$$

Comment: I always look at your answers with awe as to what is equivalents ? Is it same as equivalence relations ?

Comment: It is an equivalence relation for functions defined near a point (possible near $\infty$). But in more detail, it means the ratio of the functions tends to $1$ (here at $\infty$). The main point is that it is compatible with multiplication and division and (with some restrictions) with composition by $\log$. It is a basic concept of *Asymptotic analysis*, together with notations $O$ and $o$. The ‘philosophy’ is to replace more or less complicated functions with simpler ones, so as to concentrate on the crux of the problem and delete irrelevant details.

Comment: Do you work in this field of mathematics (It is analysis if I am correct) ? as I only seen you use this notation.

Comment: Sometimes other people use it, quite scarcely. Yes, I'm  a mathematician,  and, no, I'm an algebraist professionally. I learnt these notions during my 1st year after high school.

Comment: In school ? I have not even heard about this till now ...

Comment: *After* high school. That  said, you can it often  makes limits computation fairly simpler.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am blind !!! Thanks for responding to my comment.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

For $x \ge 2$ we have

$0 \le \frac{^3\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x + 3}} \le \frac{\sqrt[3]{2x}}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Your turn!

Answer (score 4):

A slightly longer way: use Generalized Binomial coefficients: 
$$
x^{-\frac{1}{6}}\frac{(1+\frac{2}{x})^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(1+\frac{3}{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}} \sim x^{-\frac{1}{6}}\frac{1+\frac{2}{x} + O(x^{-2})}{1+\frac{3}{x} + O(x^{-2}) } \to_x 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+3}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]x}{\sqrt x}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac2x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac3x}}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $x +2 < x + 3$.

(Yes, really, you can solve it using this.)

Comment: @juniven hints are pretty allowed here.